# How do I sort a list with recursion without using the "sort" function?

Tags: python, list, recursion

I need to sort a list without the "sort" function using recursion

```
def gensort(L):
    """ sorts all numbers in the List from lowest to highest
    L is a list
    return value is the sorted list
    """
    if len(L) == 0:
        return goodlist
    else:
        goodlist = []
        goodlist.append(min(L))
        L.remove(min(L))
        return gensort(L)
gensort([7, 9, 4, 3, 0, 5, 2, 6, 1, 8])
```

I wanted to create a second list and use append and remove to fill it up, but because of the nature of recursion; the list gets empdied every recursion dept.

Comment: The most obviously wrong thing is that `return goodlist` is happening before `goodlist` is defined or has values appended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to keep track of two lists. The following works fine:

```
def gensort(L):
    if len(L) == 1:
        return L
    sorted_list = [min(L)]
    L.remove(min(L))
    return sorted_list + gensort(L)
```

Here's what's happening:

```
gensort([4, 1, 3, 2]) # returns [1] + gensort([4, 3, 2])
gensort([4, 3, 2]) # returns [2] + gensort([4, 3])
gensort([4, 3]) # returns [3] + gensort([4])
gensort([4]) # returns [4]
```

Substituting in the return values, you get:

```
[1] + [2] + [3] + [4]
```

Which evaluates to `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a list on each call of gensort(). Instead of getting only one argument, make it take two (the original list and the new list). Then use an empty list as default, like this:

```
def gensort(L, goodlist=[]):
    """ sorts all numbers in the List from lowest to highest
    L is a list
    return value is the sorted list
    """
    if len(L) == 0:
       return goodlist
    else:
       goodlist.append(min(L))
       L.remove(min(L))
       return gensort(L, goodlist)

   print(gensort([7, 9, 4, 3, 0, 5, 2, 6, 1, 8]) )
```

This way, you keep the list at each recursive call.